Springboot @Transactional behavior
I have a strange behavior that i don't understand because is seems to not behave like in the documentation that i've read, i'm using springboot 3.2.4
I have a service class with a methodA marked with springboot @Transactional and witch save an entity by callling the entity repository (witch extends PagingAndSortingRepository), this methodA call a private methodB witch save another entity by callling the entity repository (witch extends JpaRepository)
If at the end in methobB i throw a RuntimeException to test transactional behavior, the 2 insertions in database are rollbacked, but i've always thought that private method doesn't participate to a transaction, and in this case it seems to participate to the transaction of methodA and i don't know why ??
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
       EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
       entityARepository.save();
       methodB();
    }

    private void methodB() {
       EntityB entityB = new EntityB();
       entityBRepository.save();
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
The insertion of 2 entities are rollbacked, not only EnitytA but also EntityB
When i put log of JpaTransactionManager, in a beginning of methodA a new transaction was created, the call to save in methodA participates of active transaction already created, the call to save in methodB also participates of active transaction already created even if methodB is private.

Transactional annotation creates a "proxy" for the object. According to specification it does not create proxy if applied to private method. But if proxy created it has full access to class fields and methods, be they private or not. Transaction starts when the method entered and committed on method exit if there is no exception on the way. If exception occurs elsewhere transaction does rollback as a method will exit abnormally

Thanks for your answer, so explanation about transaction and private method is this article is false : https://blog.stackademic.com/best-practices-for-using-transactional-in-spring-boot-dc76a0ceea13 (Private Methods and @Transactional), i found many articles about transaction that explain transactional doesn't work with private method and it seems to be false

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html#transaction-declarative-annotations-method-visibility

So, with this "As of 6.0, protected or package-visible methods can also be made transactional for class-based proxies by default", it seems that behavior changes with spring 6 for the privates methods (even if it's not very clear)

I think if nothing said about private they are still not eligible for annotation. But it is another question. We are talking about public transactional methods that call private method and the later is included in transaction too.
The TransactionDefinition interface specifies:
Propagation: Typically, all code within a transaction scope runs in that transaction. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/strategies.html


Thanks a lot, now i understand the concept of @Transactional not directly applicable to a private method and a private method called in a transactional scope of a public method.

Yes, you are right
